# How to submit a form using Jsoup without the submit button having a name?

Tags: java, android, html, forms, jsoup

I have a site form that I want to submit. The problem is that the submit button of this site doesn't have a name.

Form html:

```
<form class="login" action="oauth" method="post" name="login">
    <input name="username" value="" id="username"/>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password"/>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

My current Java code

```
Document response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .data("username", "username")
                .data("password", "reallygoodpassword")
                .data("", "Login") //But how to tag the button here? 
                .post();
```

Or is this not possible with Jsoup? If not, is there an alternative way of filling out a form that would work on this?

Comment: Do you really have to post a value for that button? You did try without already?

Comment: If I just fill in "" or null, it gives an error that it can't be empty

Comment: The button is not part of the data form. In html, button "value" attribute only stands for the button label. You should remove it from your post command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit the form from your favorite browser and see how it handles this case. Don't forget to show the Network tab from the developer tool of your browser.

Once you know how the browser handles this case, do the same in your code.